# Legacy VB6 Application Access To SQL Database Migration

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, dao

My company has vb6 application with more than 100 forms. application was developed using VB6 and Access.
Now my company wants me to convert existing application from MS Access to SQL Server.
Application is using DAO to connect with Access. I've already convert Access Database to SQL With data.
Then I changed

```
Private db As Database
Set db = OpenDatabase(Access_File_Path, dbDriverComplete, False, ";pwd=access_password;")
```

to

```
Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, False, "odbc;dsn=Database_ODBC_Name")
```

All select,insert, update, delete queries works fine.
but I am getting error on such line

```
.Recordset.AddNew
.Recordset.Delete
.Recordset.Update
.Recordset.CancelUpdate
```

getting errors like

> Runtime Error 3027 Cannot Update, Database or Object is read only

and

> ODBC Error

Any solution or way to use existing code with SQL ?

Comment: [Migration from Access to SQL in VB6 with DAO](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59aa81e0-5073-488f-8e5e-0ee67ea7694a/migration-from-ms-access-to-sql-2008-in-vb60-with-dao?forum=vblanguage) ;).

Answer (score 0):

As your error message say:

The database is read-only for one of these reasons:

- You used the OpenDatabase method and opened the database for read-only access.
- In Microsoft Visual Basic, you are using the Data control, and you set the ReadOnly property to True.
- The database file is defined as read-only in the operating system or by your network.
- The database file is stored on read-only media.
- In a network environment, you do not have write privileges for the database file.
- When working with a secured database, the database or one of its objects (such as a field or table) may be set to read-only. You may not have permission to access this data with your user name and password.

Close the database, resolve the read-only condition, and then reopen the file for read/write access.